# Centering a table in a figure environment

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have the following code which I am trying to use to show the image of the lo shu magic square being translated into its numeric magic square equivalent:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=150pt]{loshu.png}
$\longrightarrow$
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
4 & 9 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 5 & 7\\
\hline
8 & 1 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The lo-shu magic square}
\label{fig:loshu}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I typeset this, the arrow is at the bottom along with the table. I'd like for the arrow and table to be aligned in the center of the figure so the transformation looks natural. Any ideas?:

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215621/producing-the-lo-shu-magic-square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the image down by half its `\height`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=150pt]{example-image}}
  $\longrightarrow$
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    4 & 9 & 2\\
    \hline
    3 & 5 & 7\\
    \hline
    8 & 1 & 6\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The lo-shu magic square}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put image and table in minipage enviroment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
\includegraphics[width=150pt]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
$\longrightarrow$
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
4 & 9 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 5 & 7\\
\hline
8 & 1 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{The lo-shu magic square}
\label{fig:loshu}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```